# My if statement to get first element from list in python is not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

Hi i'm new to python and creating my first program using beautiful soup I have
an if statement that i want to use.  I want to see if I pull back the first element is true.  I"m getting a syntax error and i have'nt figured out how to fix it. This is my lastest iteration of my code where i add a header before i iterate over the remaining elements

[image: Mycurrent Output with current Code]
  [image: Page that I'm using scraper on]

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req = requests.get("http://espn.go.com/college-football/rankings")

soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "lxml")

g_data = soup.find_all("tr")
myCaptions = soup.find_all("caption")
print "Here are the college-football Rankings for 2015"

if myCaptions[0]:
    print "College Football Playoff Rankings" #Lets print the first header

for rows in g_data:

    contro = 0
    try:
        ranking = rows.contents[0].find_all("span")[0].text
        myTeam = rows.contents[1].find_all("span", {"class": "team-names"})[0].text
        myRecord = rows.find_all("td")[2].text
        print ranking + "  " + myTeam + " " + myRecord
    except:
        pass
    contro = contro + 1
```

Comment: Python told you where it found the syntax error. You really need to share that with us. I see several errors including the `if`'s in the `try:` block not being indented properly and `if contro == 0` missing a colon. But you need to give us the details of the error you see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have an indentation error - `contro = 0` is strangely indented for some reason.

Also, if you want to check the truthiness of a value, there is no need to explicitly compare it to `True`, just use `if myCaptions[0]:`.

---

Anyway, there is no need for `find_all()` in the first place - if you want to check if an element found. Instead, use `find()` and check if the result is not `None`:

```
caption = rows.find("caption")        
if caption is not None:  # "if caption:" would also work
    print "College Football Playoff Rankings"
```

---

Here is how would I approach the problem of locating multiple tables with captions:

```
for table in soup.find_all("table", class_="rankings"):
    caption = table.find("caption").get_text(strip=True)

    print caption

    for row in table.find_all("tr")[1:-1]:

        ranking = row.find("span", class_="number")
        ranking = ranking.get_text() if ranking else "Unknown ranking"
        myTeam = row.find("span", class_="team-names").get_text()
        myRecord = row.find_all("td")[2].text

        print ranking + "  " + myTeam + " " + myRecord

    print "----"
```

Works for me, printing:

```
College Football Playoff Rankings
1  Clemson 13-0
2  Alabama 12-1
3  Michigan State 12-1
...
24  Temple 10-3
25  USC 8-5
----
AP Top 25
1  Clemson 13-0
2  Alabama 12-1
...
```

Comment: Thanks alecxe for the quick response.  The only reason i did a find_all is because in my rest of my code there is certain elements at certain indexes  that i'm checking to see where i'm at so i can provide the correct print statement.

Comment: @skinnyWill sure, could you please provide the complete code of your script so we have a more clear picture here? Thanks.

Comment: Hi alecxe,  I added my full coded. It was working but i wanted to add the header to separate my all my rows of data. Its not complete.

Comment: @skinnyWill thanks, also could you please provide the desired output?

Comment: hi alecxe, i have added two screen shot 1 showing the page i'm scraping and the other showing my current output?. Thanks